# Make an application with Delphi plus vgscene minimize and then restore

Tags: delphi

how to Minimize the  transparency vgscene form?   i use this code

```
Application.Minimize;
```

and  i active the form from windows Taskbar,
but   every  Components  of  vgscene form   can not be click !

Comment: Some people might still use vgScene/dxScene if they were previous customers of the old company ksdev.  You could say vgScene = Firemonkey version 0.1. I frankly doubt very many StackOverflow users even known what VgScene was, let alone still use it.

Comment: What's your Windows version ? Same for VGScene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type
  tmain1 = class(TForm)
   private
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;


procedure tmain1.WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand);
begin
  inherited;
    vgScene1.Transparency:=True ;
```

when the form  Minimize....

```
 vgScene1.Transparency:=False;
    Application.Minimize;
```